# Am I able to complete Horde mode as a single player?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I have been playing Horde mode in private matches with two players and it has been really, really tough going. I just wondered, is it possible to complete Horde mode (all 50 waves) with just one person?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least for me, the answer is definitely no. The game throws way too many enemies at you for you to be able to have success on your own. I can't imagine surviving the first boss wave (wave 10) on my own, when it throws multiple Reavers, Berserkers, or a Bromak (sp) at you.

It would be cool if they made a version that could be played by yourself, but as it stands today you need a group to hope to complete all 50 waves.

Answer (score 7):

There's no *technical* reason why one person couldn't complete Horde mode alone; it completely depends on the skill of the player. While this may be difficult for most players, it is not impossible to imagine that the more skilled players could finish it on their own. Personal experience is irrelevant.

EDIT: As a proof-of-concept, I successfully completed through the first boss wave by myself. I'm very certain that if someone had the skill and the patience to go through all 50 waves by themselves, they could.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst looking for the answer to this question for the new Gears of War 4 mode I've hardly played since it's took me from early release till the day before yesterday to finish the campaign, on insane, on my own.

Just thought I'd mention I did 50 waves solo many times on Gears 3 on insane!

Tip, I use to always pick blood drive and after two waves by a turret, then about wave six, get the silver back and get in the room were it's at the top of the stairs were you start and you shouldn't have a problem.

I think I did about six-and-a-half thousands waves on Gears three, but I have not got much to go off for Gears 4 yet. So, in answer to the question,

50 waves is possible solo, even on insane.
I did it many times and had great leveling system as well. 
Think I did it aswel were enemies regenerate health
U need an active reload or the guns jam an I forget what the other hard mutator I had was sorry no I think I had instagib on incase an hunkers blocked up the doorway an also bought rockets for the silverback and a sentry which was on my right while I'm on the left side of the doorway
The silverback turret comes from its right arm so u can fire staying relatively covered by the wall and u can upgrade to maximum fence for the doorway

It does get a bit hard but once u have the rockets it's all about when to fire them reload them and switching it up with the mini gun but writing this brings back memories of the chaos I got threw

It was insane but so glad I got the routine but
Once wave 50 popped the levelling of the ribbons alone was insane 
Needless to say I was a rank 400 gear on gears 3
Hope this helps anyone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's entirely possible. I have a very bad internet connection and keep getting d/c out of matches so I went at horde alone. If you unlock 3 specific mutators it is ridiculously easy to win (with a lot of restarts mind you) and unless you keep getting berserkers in the boss levels you can coast by.

- Instigab Meelee (1 hit KO)
- Super Reload (Do an active reload and the clip size doubles and the first few shots are at double power. This is **stronger** than a Mulcher's bullet.)
- Infinite Ammo (Starter weapons and all pistols get infinite ammo)

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is possible. I just cleared out all 50 waves of horde mode alone.

Answer (score -1):

I managed 47 waves on casual with out dying on over pass, with super reload. a boomer took me out on the 47 wave! setting up 3 hammer of dawn strikes helped for boss wave 40. I will try all 50 waves again soon with out dying. as mentioned before reaves numbers can be a problem in the last two boss waves ( 40 & 50) when you on your own.